# Error installing homebrew on mac

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew using this command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

and getting the following error:

```
-e:4: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     ^
-e:5: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <html>
     ^
-e:7: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
     ^
-e:8: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
     ^
-e:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
```

I'm new to Ruby and Homebrew, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that command?  I think you should just try running the command listed on the front page of http://brew.sh.  The command is:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"
```

The problem with the command you are running is that it loads an HTML webpage and tries to run it in Ruby.  The command from the front page of brew.sh actually loads a Ruby script.

Comment: It's working.  I got my command from http://blog.zerosharp.com/installing-ruby-with-homebrew-and-rbenv-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: It's always a good idea to follow the instructions on the source site itself, rather than on someone else's second, or third, party site. The people who wrote it usually have a little better idea how it works.